# Have control over the rights of a tab/window created within a chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm developping a chrome extension, it is tab-based so I'm playing with the `chrome.tabs` API.

There is a **master** tab in which my verified secured JS code executes, and it can open other **child** tabs in which some JS code (not necessarly verified/secured) executes.

I need to control the authorizations for the **child** tab I openned. The **children** tabs should only be able to sendMessage with `chrome.tabs.sendMessage`. At the moment they can access all the features of the `chrome` and `chrome.tabs` API (move tabs, duplicate tabs, open new window etc...) in the case of my extension, it is an open XSS breach.

**Question:** Is it possible to restrict the rights of a newly create tab ? Or all the tabs have by default all the rights and there is no way to control it ?

See https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#method-create

I'd like to to something like the following:

`const tab = chrome.tabs.create({ restrictedMethods: ['chrome.tabs.sendMessage'] })`

Thanks for your help

Comment: My extension is like a mini-browser, you enter a URL of some JS ressource, it gets loaded and executed in another tab. I have no control over what's executed in the **children** tabs, the JS code can be some React JS app code, some simple vanilla JS, or any other front-end javascript. This is why I must make sure that in the tab context, there is no access to `chrome` `chrome.windows`, `chrome.tabs` APIs.

Comment: So far I think you'll have to use sandboxed iframes, either via the `sandbox` HTML attribute or [sandbox declaration in manifest.json](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/sandbox).

Comment: In my main tab:
fetch(URL_OF_SOME_JS_CODE_ENTERED_BY_USER).then(code => {
    chrome.tabs.create({ url 'app.html' }, (tab) => {
        chrome.tabs.sendMessage(tab.id, code)
    });
});


app.html file:
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <body>
</html>


app.js file:
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
      eval(request.code);
  });
);

Comment: More readable here -> https://gist.github.com/Rafkraft/2e0645334898ba650ae30866f141e883

Comment: Ok thanks very much, this is what I need :)

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to prevent access to `chrome.*` for a new tab by listing the file as **sandboxed** in the extension's manifest.

This way it is executed in an isolated environment.

https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/manifest/sandbox
https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/sandboxingEval

Thanks very much for your help